# How to make Language drop down selector for android application? (localization)

Tags: android, localization

Okay, i've been searching on google and I actually DID find some tutorials but they were all like just changing language just for that moment. i mean i downloaded several Samples it did work actually when i hit the drop down spinner and change it to Spanish. BUT when i close the App and open it up again it's get its current language (English) again. so please help me out with this, i wanna make an app that the user can change language of the app and its save itself. like when you choose Spanish and close the app and open it again its still Spanish not the current Language...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save your desired language to `SharedPreferences`, then each time you starty any of your app activities get value from `SharedPreferences` and set your language according to it.

Create `AbstractBaseActivity` (it doesn't have to be abstract), and make sure that all of your activities extend it. Put your `changeLanguage()` function in `AbstarctBaseActivity` `onCreate` method.

Example:
http://snowpard-android.blogspot.com/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html